# SQL insert into statement gone wrong

Tags: sql-server, insert

Okay, so i have looked up basic examples of the INSERT INTO for SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and they are fairly straight forward.  However, i'm getting an "Incorrect syntax near..." error and i have no idea why.

For example, if i have database MyDatabase with a dbo schema and a table named MyTable with an integer column named MyColumn and i wanted to insert a value of 1 i would make an INSERT INTO statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] (MyColumn, INT) VALUES (1)
```

However, it gives me the following error: "Incorrect syntax near 'MyColumn'" and i am not sure what i'm supposed to do to get this to work.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `INT` is a datatype. you don't need it when inserting a value.use `INSERT INTO [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] (MyColumn) VALUES (1)`

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of the column list for `INSERT INTO` uses column names without column types. Column types are specified when you create your schema; when you are doing an insert, RDBMS does not need you to specify the column type, because it already knows it.

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] (MyColumn) VALUES (1)
```

Comment: Okay, that gives me the following error: Invalid object name 'MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable'.  Any advice on how to eliminate that error? I keep spinning in circles trying to figure this one out, i feel.

Comment: Do you have `MyTable` defined in the `MyDatabase` database instance?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely there and i copy and pasted the table and database names so i'm sure i spelled those correctly.

Comment: @user1789573 Could you try right-clicking the database `MyDatabase` in SQL Management Studio, choosing "New Query", then trying your `INSERT INTO` but without the three-part identifier, i.e. `INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn) VALUES (1)`

Comment: Sweet!  That did it for me!  Hurray and thank you soo so much Dasblinkenlight! You just brightened my day...no pun intended.